# Jekyll: How can I override (?) page created from data with a user-generated page?

Tags: jekyll

**Short version:** is there a method/approach to overriding (for lack of a better term?) pages that I've created from a data file using the [jekyll-datapage_gen](https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen) plugin with a manually created page?

**Longer version:**

I'm playing with Jekyll to create a site that tracks the mountains I want to climb.  I have two yaml files right now from which I'm generating my site content:

1. `checklists.yml`: a list of lists of peaks (e.g. county high points, wilderness area high points, etc.)
2. `peaks.yml`: a list of all the peaks with their associated metadata (e.g. elevation, prominence, isolation, etc.).  I also have a "complete" column where

Right now, I've got a page with a list of my checklists at `www.example.com/checklists`.  Then I'm using [jekyll-datapage_gen](https://github.com/avillafiorita/jekyll-datapage_gen) to autogenerate pages for each individual checklist at `www.example.com/checklists/foo_list` and each individual peak on the checklist at `www.example.com/peaks/foo_peak`.  So far so good.

As I actually hike some of these peaks, I want to write a trip report on the experience, add some photos, etc.  Is there a way to "override" the page I generated above at `www.example.com/peaks/foo_peak` with my own content, and still have it display at `www.example.com/peaks/foo_peak` without trying to cram in all my blog content into the yaml file?  I could write a script that creates the individual pages at `/peaks/` for me, but that also seems messy (and error-prone).  Is there a way to achieve what I'm attempting to do within Jekyll itself?

Comment: Couldn't you just generate a markdown version of the file?

Comment: Of which file?  Can you elaborate on what you're envisioning?